# Problem with login after power outage

Tags: login, password

I know similar questions have already been asked here, but they all seem  to be different from my problem.

After a power outage I cannot login locally with my main user. I can ssh into it with the same credentials.

Locally I can login as any other user but not the one that was logged in at the time of the power-down.

When I type in my password at the login screen I just get referred back to the login screen.
If I deliberately type in a wrong password I get a "wrong password" message.
But with the correct password I cannot get past the login screen.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer myself, sorry for the spam ;-)

In any case if someone else got the same problem, here is what fixed it:

the permissions for the users home folder were all set to d--------- for that user. After setting them back to something usefull with

```
find /home/username -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

and

```
find /home/username -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

everything is working fine again...

One question remains though, how could a power outage possibly cause this problem?????

Comment: A possible reason could be the data to be written by a program were still in the buffer, so after power outage the file system hierarchy starts to behave abnormally.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, sounds reasonable...

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer to your question so that others can be aware that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: "you can accept your own answer in 2 days"... so i will come back and do so on monday :-)